# Getting X window id for GLUT program? or, How to remote control a GLUT program on X?

Tags: x11, glut, chipmunk, freeglut

I want to send a keystroke to a GLUT program on X11, but I can't find there's an X11 client attached to the GLUT program.

I do this, using the most excellent demo program for the chipmunk 2d physics package:

```
xlsclients -a|sort >aa
chipmunk_demos  (in another window)
xlsclients -a|sort >bb
diff aa bb
```

and there's no difference.

My eventual hope is that I can control the GLUT program by sending key events with the equivalent of:

```
xdotool key --window 0x4000002 a
```

So my questions:

1. how can I remote control a GLUT program running on linux/X11?
2. Is there a way to get an X11 window id for a GLUT program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install xtrace, then:

In Terminal 1:

`xtrace -d :0 -D :8 | grep CreateWindow`

In Terminal 2:

`DISPLAY=:8 chipmunk_demos`

You should get a line with:

... CreateWindow depth=0x18 **window=0x04a00002** ...

**Update:** `xdotool` actually contains powerful search functionality, which recent versions make even easier to use.  It doesn't make sense to use `xtrace` like this, just use `xdotool search` instead